# spyOn multiple $broadcasts or ignore one of them

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I have code that listens on a broadcast, performs some actions when it receives it and then broadcasts something itself too.

How can I build a unit test that listens for that second broadcast? I'm ok with testing for both, or ignoring the first, but at the moment the spyOn catches only the first broadcast, the one I trigger myself in the unit test.

Comment: What are you trying to test for?  What is the expectation?  Are you just trying to test that the second `$broadcast` happened? or what?

Comment: right, that it happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it: You can do the following:

```
spyOn($scope, '$broadcast').andCallThrough();
```

This way both calls show up and can be expected:

```
expect($scope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('triggerApp');
expect($scope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('appResponse');
```